# Comparing non nullable `int` to `null` (LINQ)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, nullable

I have EF model class and I've decided to extend that class with one `bool` property:

```
class A 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class A_DTO : A
{
    public bool BoolProp { get; set; }
}


class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int A_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote a method, which will return that `A` collection joined with some other `C` collection, which contains A <=> C mapping (well, in real world example it contains some `SystemId` and linq query will be joined by 2 columns) and returns `A_DTO` collection:

```
internal IQueryable<A_DTO> MyMethod() => 
    from a in dbContext.A
    join c in dbContext.A_C_Mapping
    on a.Id equals c.A_Id into g
    from cc in gg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new A_DTO
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Value = a.Value,
        BoolProp = cc.A_Id != null //<- will be always true, well, that what says warning message
    }
```

(`dbContext` is my EF context object)

and of course because of `cc.A_Id` is not a nullable `int` the warning message will appear, saying that

> *"The result of expression will be always `'true'` since the value of type `int` is never equal to `null` value of type `int?`"*

which is true, but in fact I get results perfectly correct, because of my left outer join return `null`s when mapping missing in `C` collection.

So the question: is it correct approach to do so and leave it as it is, or I need to implement it another way?

Comment: Since your whole expression is converted to SQL query and not really executed by .NET framework - that warning doesn't matter, so you can just disable it (for this specific line of course).

Comment: @Evk yeap, I know that, thanks for answering, I just wanted to be sure that it was correct approach to do so.

Comment: Well you see yourself that it's a false warning - so what could be wrong in disabling it?

Comment: @Evk Sometimes it's not necessarily "wrong(?)" to do something and there is "more desirable" ways to do that.

Comment: @GertArnold As I said before, in real life example, there is left outer join with 2 columns, for example `C` table stores some `SystemId` and `A_Id`, so you can get which `A_Id`s belong to your system.

Comment: @GertArnold yeap, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [DefaultIfEmpty method definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx), the following code snippets are equivalent:

```
List<C> list = new List<C>() { }; // empty list
List<C> listDefault = list.DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();
```

and

```
List<C> listDefault = new List<C>() { null }; // Since default(C) is null
```

Thus when you use g.DefaultIfEmpty() you will get a unique cc object which is null, consequently the line:

```
BoolProp = cc.A_Id != null
```

will throw a NullReferenceException because cc is null.

At the end it seems that the condition should be:

```
BoolProp = cc != null
```

Besides here is a small example which demonstrates the difference through a unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod_DefaultifEmpty()
    {
        ListA = new List<A>()
        {
            new A { Id=1, Value="111" },
            new A { Id=2, Value="222" },
        };
        ListC = new List<C>()
        {
            new C { Id=1,  A_Id=1 }
        };

        Assert.AreEqual(2, MyMethod().Count());
    }

    public List<A> ListA { get;  set; }
    public List<C> ListC { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<A_DTO> MyMethod() =>
                    from a in ListA
                    join c in ListC
                    on a.Id equals c.A_Id into g
                    from cc in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new A_DTO
                    {
                        Id = a.Id,
                        Value = a.Value,
                        //BoolProp = cc.A_Id != null
                        BoolProp = cc != null // replace by previous line to see the difference
                    };
```

Comment: In fact `BoolProp = cc.A_Id != null` is not throwing any exceptions, but `BoolProp = cc != null` makes sense, so I think it'll be more accurate to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the cc.A_Id is never going to become null and you want to set the value for BoolProp then you can remove the warning by changing your select to be the following:

```
select new A_DTO
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Value = a.Value,
    BoolProp = true
}
```

Comment: That what's says warning message, but in fact I get `false` values too.

Answer (score 0):

`Value Types` will always have a default value (exception when declaring them as `Nullable`) even when they are not initalized, even if you are using a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) through `LINQ`. Thus `A_ID` will always have a value, and `BoolProp` will always be true.

On the other hand, `Reference Types` will default to `NULL`.

Comment: I've edited my question with implementation of `C`, the `A_Id` is not nullable.

Comment: I have now replicated the warning, let me check.